# Generating loops using Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

[image]I'm attempting to create ideal motorcycle routes (a tourism map) using network analyst, I have an attribute for road curvature. So far I've been able to do two things: create routes using either popular destinations (hotels, restaurants, etc...) or the midpoints to road segments with low sinuosity as stops. The problem which is clearly illustrated in the map below, is that network analyst doesn't create loops. It will go to a destination and then back tract away from it. Ideally if someone is merely going for a "joyride" they would be able to continue on their route with option of forking off to destinations along the route.

The only solution I've found is to preserve the first and last destination and a new destination on top of first one. Then after solving the route again, it will loop back to the first point. But I would like to improve it so that their are several loops. I'm hoping to create enough so that riders could find a loop around their area, but still be able to get to other loops.

Any additional ideas?

[image]

I've added an idealized map above, the green is a closed loop and the red lines are off-shoots to destinations.

Comment: Interesting one. Could you please draw on the figure how this "ideal" route would look like? I am having hard time trying to formalize it in terms that NA could understand.

Comment: The NA task is to find the best (in terms of cost) route between multiple destinations. Your task doesn't make sense in terms of the algorithm. Your best shoot would be probably using multiple destinations and then as you have done and then adding/removing destination points along the route to make it look as you wish.